# How do I add an icon via Stylesheet using PyInstaller --onefile option with resource_path in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qtstylesheets

So basically what I want to do is add a down arrow to a combobox via Stylesheet(QSS) so I can bundle the py.file with --onefile option using PyInstaller: 
The code is this but it doesn't seem to work :

```
QComboBox::drop-down{
    image: url(resource_path("icon_example.png"))
}
```

and the resource_path method is :

```
def resource_path(self,relative_path):
    try:
       base_path = sys._MEIPASS
     except Exception:
       base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
     return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Comment: provide a [MRE]

Answer (score 1):

It's an old topic, but my answer could be useful for others (widely inspired by https://forum.qt.io/topic/17318/solved-using-variables-in-style-sheets-qss/11)

As mentioned, the *.spec file must contain a link to the files to include in the *.exe:

```
added_files = [
    ( './images', 'images' ),
    ( './fonts', 'fonts' )
]

a = Analysis(['MyScript.py'],
             [...]
             datas=added_files
             [...]
```

The function to get the relative path:

```
def relative_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Then replace the text "iconExample" inside the styleSheet by the variable (relative path) iconExample:

```
iconExample = relative_path("./images/icon_example.png")).replace("\\", "/")

styleSheet = '''
QComboBox::drop-down{
    image: url(iconExample);
}
'''
styleSheet = styleSheet.replace("iconExample", iconExample)
myWidget.setStyleSheet(styleSheet)
```

I don't know if it's the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is what I used and it worked perfectly.

```
import sys
from os.path import join, abspath
def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return join(abspath("."), relative_path)
```

Add the following code in `spec` file:

```
a.datas += [ ('back.png', 'icon/back.png', 'DATA')]
```

where `'back.png'` is my image path will be saved in pyinstaller exe bundle, and `'icon/back.png'` is I put my image file in `icon` folder currently before packaging.

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\GitHub\\Mypath'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['mkl','whl'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)

a.datas += [ ('back.png', 'icon/back.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [ ('main.ico', 'icon/main.ico', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [ ('folder.png', 'icon/folder.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [ ('download.png', 'icon/download.png', 'DATA')]

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True , icon='icon\\main.ico')
```

Then you can call you image like `resource_path('download.png')`

Comment: I wanted to give you the answer but you didnt answer 100%. Like how do i use resource_path inside a stylesheet. Thats my whole problem.

Comment: Just use it as your code in question, use `resource_path("icon_example.png")` as image path.

Comment: The most important part is that you should add `a.datas += [ ('icon_example.png', 'yourPath/icon_example.png', 'DATA')]` in `spec` file so that you can use `resource_path` to call your image after bundle your py file.

Comment: resource_path works in regular python code but not in stylesheet code for me even with adding the files in the spec file. The images wont get loaded inside the stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

you should use absolute path in qss url reference. you can use a function to repalce that path content and then config your icon path into the *.exe in .spec file.

for example in qss file:

```
QComboBox::down-arrow
{
    image: url(QSS/QSS_IMG/arrow-down.png);
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
}


def replace_qss_path(content: str)->str:
    base_path = getattr(sys,"_MEIPASS",os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.abspath(__file__)))))
    p = re.compile("url *[(](.*?)[)]", re.S)
    c_l = re.findall(p, content)
    for item in c_l:
        if not item.startswith(":"):
            content = content.replace(item, os.path.join(base_path, item).replace("\\","/"))
    return content

def get_qss():
    with open(resource_path("QSS/Integrid.qss"), "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        content = f.read()
        return replace_qss_path(content)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWin):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setStyleSheet(get_qss())
```

and in main.spec:

```
datas=[("E:/QSS/Integrid.qss", "QSS"),
 ("E:/QSS/QSS_IMG/*","QSS/QSS_IMG")
 ]
```