What do to, when pyinstaller sys._MEIPASS does not work?
Here is an example, which in fact works, and so it does not actually illustrate my problem, but just to set a basis for discussion:
mkdir C:/test/testpyinst
cd C:/test/testpyinst

Here I have main.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, os

from lib import relative_path2

def relative_path(relative_path): # https://stackoverflow.com/q/58487122
  try:
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    print("_MEIPASS OK {}".format(base_path))
  except Exception:
    base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
    print("_MEIPASS exception {}".format(base_path))
  return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


def main():
  print("Hello from main")
  print("relative_path {}".format(relative_path(".")))
  print("relative_path2 {}".format(relative_path2(".")))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

... and lib.py:
import sys, os

def relative_path2(relative_path): # https://stackoverflow.com/q/58487122
  try:
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    print("_MEIPASS OK {}".format(base_path))
  except Exception:
    base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
    print("_MEIPASS exception {}".format(base_path))
  return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

I use this - pyinstaller installed via python3 -m pip install pyinstaller:
$ uname -s
MINGW64_NT-10.0-19045

$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.8

$ pyinstaller --version
6.5.0

When I run this code directly from python, _MEIPASS is as expected not accessible:
$ python3 main.py
Hello from main
_MEIPASS exception C:/test/testpyinst
relative_path C:/test/testpyinst/.
_MEIPASS exception C:/test/testpyinst
relative_path2 C:/test/testpyinst/.

Then I create an .exe with PyInstaller:
pyinstaller --onefile main.py

... and when I run the .exe, as expected, _MEIPASS works:
$ ./dist/main.exe
Hello from main
_MEIPASS OK D:\msys64\tmp\_MEI199762
relative_path D:\msys64\tmp\_MEI199762/.
_MEIPASS OK D:\msys64\tmp\_MEI199762
relative_path2 D:\msys64\tmp\_MEI199762/.


So, here is my problem - in my actual (pyqt5) project, sys._MEIPASS does not work - in the sense that I always get an exception in relative_path() when trying to read sys._MEIPASS while running from the final .exe created by PyInstaller !?
I found this AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_MEIPASS' (redux) · Issue #1785 · pyinstaller/pyinstaller:

sys._MEIPASS is set by the exe produced by pyinstaller before it runs any python code. I can think of a few reasons why it would not be set:

The code reload(sys) is executed
You are using a version of PyInstaller prior to 3.0
PyInstaller was improperly installed and is using the old 2.1 bootloader files


I have tried running python3 -m trace --trace myprogram.py | grep reload, and apparently reload(sys) is never called in my program ...
So, I am still at a loss: what can I possibly do in my project, to get sys._MEIPASS working as expected?

General solution: move the def relative_path as close as possible to the top of your main file (main file would be the one being supplied to PyInstaller e.g. __init__.py), possibly after the very first import sys, os - at the very start, sys._MEIPASS should work properly (and this can help you identify later on what exact library causes the problem).
